# Dataflow is failing java.io.IOException on g1-small instances

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying Wordcount example provided by google. It is running successfully when I run it from my local machine.

But when I run it through Google Cloud, it fails with the following exception,

```
java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: Finalize rejected (writer id not found) when talking to tcp://localhost:12345
```

The exception is not clear as well.

I found that this happens when any of the Job is Part running and the job after that is not running.

[image]

So When I removed the Sum.Perkey transform it was running successfully.

Like the one below.
[image]

**EDIT 1**

The log says the following

```
    Jun 23, 2015, 5:21:27 PM
(306b526c890d6a9e): java.io.IOException: INTERNAL: Finalize rejected (writer id not found) when talking to tcp://localhost:12345 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ApplianceShuffleWriter.close(Native Method) at 

com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.close(ChunkingShuffleEntryWriter.java:66) at 

com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ShuffleSink$ShuffleSinkWriter.close(ShuffleSink.java:232) at 

com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.finish(WriteOperation.java:100) at 

com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:74) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:130) at 

com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:95) at

 com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:139) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:124) at 

java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at 

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at 

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My Job Id is : 2015-06-23_04_49_22-5338020413017331855

Please help me why this is happening.

Comment: Sorry about this issue. To help us investigate, can you edit the question to include the complete output of a failing pipeline, including the job ID?

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you refer to complete output? is it the exception it gave when failed??

Comment: Yes, I mean the output that the main program prints to console, e.g. like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872174/using-cloud-dataflow-side-input-works-locally-but-not-when-executing-in-the-c

Comment: I see you edited the question - however this is output of the workers from Cloud Logging (please keep it - it's also useful), while I meant the console output of the main program which submits the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue.

I set the work machine type in my pipeline options to

```
g1-small
```

Previously i was using

```
f1-micro
```

When we use Combine or GroupBy Transforms, we have to use g1-small work machine it seems.

However i couldn't find this information anywhere in the dataflow documentation.

It would be nice if Google documents how to uses the compute engine instance for dataflow.
That would have saved a lot of my time.

Comment: Why are you setting the machine type explicitly rather than letting Dataflow pick it?